# How to Sort ListView Items in Ascending Order?

Tags: qt, sorting, qt4.7, qlistview, qstandarditemmodel

I Tried to Sort my ListView Items in Ascending Order,  so i tried with

```
Model->sort(int Column, Qt::AscendingOrder)
```

It Works Fine, but I don't like the Qt::AscendingOrder policy. Indeed the function first sorts words beginning with an uppercase character and then sorts the other words starting with a lowercase character. Then it concatenates both results together.
For Eg:

```
My ListView Items are: apple
                       Ball
                       rose
                       cat
                       Orange

And i'm getting the output as:  Ball
                                Orange
                                apple
                                cat
                                rose
```

Is there any way to customize the Sort Policy? Plz Help me... Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why don't you just write your own sort function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `QSortFilterProxyModel` and set [`sortCaseSensitivity`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#sortCaseSensitivity-prop) to `Qt::CaseInsensitive` should do the trick.

Or derive your own model and override [`sort()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#sort)

Comment: Hi.. I tried with **QSortFilterProxyModel**, even after that i can't able to sort. **The o/p remains the same**. And another doubt is **QTreeView** and **QTableView** has the **setSortingEnabled** property, but why the QListView doesn't have that? can u please elaborate with ur piece of code. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a trick. Add an extra column with the same labels, but convert them to lower case. Apply sort to this column.